# https GET works with basic node app but not with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, get, create-react-app

So I've gotten a console app to make a **successful** request to my https server with this:

```
console.log('Initializing...')

const https = require('https')

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'

const options = {
    port: '3001',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/data',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic correct'
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log(d.toString())
    })
})

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('error: ' + e.message)
})

req.end()
```

However, when I try to transfer this over to a project made with **create-react-app**:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import https from 'https'

import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)


document.getElementById('p').textContent = 'test'


process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'

const options = {
    port: '3001',
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/data',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic correct'
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, (response) => {
    response.on('data', (d) => {
        document.getElementById('p').textContent = d.toString()
    })
})

req.on('error', (e) => {
    document.getElementById('p').textContent = e.message
})

req.end()
```

I get '**XHR Error**'. I'm not exactly sure on what to do, I have tried a few different things (such as using fetch on the client-side) but it looks like I need some help.

Side-note: the server doesn't pick up the request, let alone respond (where as with the other request everything is successful)

(I'm using https because I like the config options available on the server-side and I thought it'd be nice to use it in both locations for simplicity vs opting for fetch or xhr)

Any response is appreciated, thanks :)

Here's the server code for people in the comments:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')

const express = require('express')
var app = express()

var port = 3001


var printReqReceived = function(request) {
    console.log('received request for ' + request + ', attempting to authorize...')
}

var printAuthenticated = function(authenticated = true, willRespond = true) {
    if(!authenticated)
        console.log('Authorization attempt revoked')
    else if(willRespond)
        console.log('Authorization attempt accepted, preparing response...')
    else
        console.log('Authorization attempt accepted')
}

var responseSent = function() {
    console.log('Response sent')
}

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
})

app.get('/bundles', function(request, response) {

})

app.get('/data', function(request, response) {
    printReqReceived('data')

    var auth = request.get('Authorization')
    if(auth.substr(auth.indexOf(' ') + 1, auth.length) == 'correct')  {

        printAuthenticated()

        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/javascript',
            'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=App.js'
        })
       fs.createReadStream('./build/static/js/main.4e81bda7.js').pipe(response)

        responseSent()

    } else {
        printAuthenticated(false)
        response.send('Authorization attempt revoked') 
    }
})


var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privateKey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false

}

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server is now listening on port ' + port + '!')
})
```

I realize that this is set up a bit funky, I'm just trying to get the request working - that's all.

If it doesn't work with `create-react-app`, do I have to use `whatwg-fetch`? (would seem strange to me since they're both doing the same thing and on top of that, I tried with `whatwg-fetch` to no avail)

Comment: Is this your server code?

Comment: I'm not sure the `https` package is available on the client side. Did you get no error from that import?

Comment: I'm confused as well, if it is client code, `https` won't work, as well as the `process.env` stuff. But if it is `node` your `document` won't work.

Comment: it's the client code - it works perfectly fine with `https` in the first code section posted, is it different in `create-react-app` then? (because it is perfectly fine without `create-react-app`, `https` and `env` included)   and no - I get no error from the `import`.

Comment: I posted the server code as well

Comment: in which port your react app works? it is different from `3001` which is the port your node app works, right?

Comment: both clients I tried are using port 3000 for themselves and making the request to 3001 (3001 being the server)